# Multiple Column Conditional Count SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

I am trying to count distinct entries in 4 separate columns in a row and then total the results.

For instance the table headers look similar to this:

```
ID       Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
```

Each column (save ID) can have a text value W, X, Y, or Z. Columns can have the same value.

What I am trying to do is figure a method for counting each entries in the columns, but only count W, X, Y, and Z once per row. So if:

```
ID       Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
          X        X       Y
          Y        W       X
          Z        Y       Y
```

The result table would be:

```
    Value    Count
      W        1
      X        2
      Y        3
      Z        1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but would this be as simple as:

```
Select Val, Count(*)
From    (
        Select Id, Col1 As Val From Table1
        Union Select Id, Col2 From Table1
        Union Select Id, Col3 From Table1
        Union Select Id, Col4 From Table1
        ) As Z
Where Z.Val Is Not Null
Group BY Z.Val
```

There is no reason to use `Distinct` and `Union` together as `Union` will make the results distinct. Because of that, we need to include the unique value for each row (`Id`).

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68aa3/14) (This uses SQL Server but the same syntax will work in MS Access)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do it for your example 4 cases:

```
select 'W' as [Value], count(*) as Count from Table1
    where Col1='W' or Col2='W' or Col3='W' or Col4='W' union
select 'X' as [Value], count(*) as Count from Table1
    where Col1='X' or Col2='X' or Col3='X' or Col4='X' union
select 'Y' as [Value], count(*) as Count from Table1
    where Col1='Y' or Col2='Y' or Col3='Y' or Col4='Y' union
select 'Z' as [Value], count(*) as Count from Table1
    where Col1='Z' or Col2='Z' or Col3='Z' or Col4='Z'
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68aa3/11

---

**Edit:**  If there are lots of possible values, this can be simplified further by unioning all possible values and counting them dynamically:

```
select V.Value as [Value],
  count(IIF(col1=[Value] or col2=[Value]
            or col3=[Value] or col4=[Value],1,NULL)) as [Count]
from Table1, (
  select distinct col1 as [Value] from table1 union
  select distinct col2 from table1 union
  select distinct col3 from table1 union
  select distinct col4 from table1) V
where V.value is not null
group by V.value
```

Comment: Your second example uses Case and it is not available in MS Access (see tags)

Comment: @Remou: Good point, I think we can use `IIF` in that case instead.

Comment: that other table idea is very good .. 

but you forget to put all this union table output into one combined query with selecting distinct value ..

Comment: Updated second example with `IIF` for MS Access.  Also updated first example to select from a table properly for MS Access. Both queries tested and worked fine for me in MS Access 2012.

Comment: ohh my mistake .. I skipped group by clause .. (+1)