# Sequential Column Where Conditional - SQL / Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

Suppose we have some data that looks like so

```
R_Id    Nm      Base       Dest    Proj      Cust_id  201203   201202   201201
MRBR    Bob     LONDON     UK      Project1  1        0        0        0
MRBU    Frank   LONDON     London  Project2  2        11.68    0        248.93
MRBU    Frank   LONDON     UK      Project3  1        7.4      4.8      0
MRGB    Barry   GUILDFORD  Hull    Project4  1        50.36    12.85    48.92
MRGB    Barry   GUILDFORD          Project5  1        0        177.31   0
MRGB    Barry   GUILDFORD  INTL    Project6  3        0        331.08   0
```

And suppose we have a lot more columns than above, but we've limited to a few for now.

I want to be able to use a where statment to only show rows where the row needs further investigation. This is done by saying "Where are there more than two large numbers next to each other in a row?" So I need to count the number of rows where the number is large.

The output should look like such, where I've explained what filtering I'm doing.

```
R_Id    Nm      Base       Dest    Proj      Cust_id  201203   201202   201201
MRBR    Bob     LONDON     UK      Project1  1        "Numbers not Large"
MRBU    Frank   LONDON     London  Project2  2        11.68    248.93   0   
MRBU    Frank   LONDON     UK      Project3  1        "Numbers not Large"
MRGB    Barry   GUILDFORD  Hull    Project4  1        50.36    12.85    48.92
MRGB    Barry   GUILDFORD          Project5  1        "Too few adjacent numbers"
MRGB    Barry   GUILDFORD  INTL    Project6  3        "Too few adjacent numbers"
```

It's the case where there are too few adjacent numbers I'm trying to filter for. I need to count the numer of adjacent (or every other!) numbers in those specific columns.

I've looked at this question: [Multiple Column Conditional Count SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10603448/1075247), but I don't think I can use Count(*) as I get this error: You tried to execute a query thaty does not include the speicified expression 'AT_RISK?' as part of aggregate function. At risk is a column that just stores Yes/No and lives to the left of R_Id (not included above for brevity)

Can anyone help or at least point me in the right direction please? I'd really appreciate it. I've read the question above, and I've looked at how to use count in general, but this is really stumping me.

Comment: Select your results as a sub-query and in the outer query you can make your aggregation.

Comment: Please clarify: "where the number of orders over 1000 is more than two consecutively" .. exactly why are rows 1, 4, and 5 being selected in our output? do you mean select the most recent consecutive order with prices more than 1000? and which price?

Comment: And exactly what are you counting? Your output looks like a sub-selection of the original data.

Comment: @nicholas I've altered the tables so it looks more like what I'm actually doing. I want to filter out the rows 2 and 3 by this conditional counting of rows, so later on I can filter by a different number of rows. In the actual data set I've done it monthly, so I'm looking for sets of 2,3,4....etc columns where there is a data pattern (i.e the number is above a certain amount).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and in this case HansUp has the correct solution (for 3 columns). See my comment on his solution below about arbitrarily large number of columns.

Comment: @nicholas I was editing the tale again when people answered, this is as near to the real table as I can get, and I've hopefully explained my methods and motivation better.

Comment: Are your columns `201203`, `201202`, ... actually stored in a table that way or are they being generated by a crosstab query? As noted below, if you are storing those quarters as actual columns, there may be no arbitrary solution to this question

Comment: @nicholas I have the select 'command' (?) drawing them in as *[Numbers by res,proj,period_Crosstab].[201109]*...so I'm guessing yes?

Comment: Oh in that case it may be easier. Please revise your post to include the *source table* schema and possibly the SQL statement of the crosstab query being used.

Comment: @nicholas I'll do this tomorrow/monday, If that's ok?

Comment: @nicholas what exactly is included in the source table schema? And is the 'SQL statement of the cross tab query' just the select commands for the cross table part?

Comment: Looks like there must be a query definition somewhere named `[Numbers by res,proj,period_Crosstab]`. That is the one we are interested in. Also, are there any gaps in the period numbers `201203`, `201202`, ... , or are they purely sequential?

Comment: No they are sequential. I still don't kow what you mean by schema in this context though. I don't really know what I'm doing...

Comment: @nicholas I mean to ping you.

Comment: For future viewers I never fixed/solved this, as I got moved off this project. If I find a solution or use one below I'll try to update appropiriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I can think of a somewhat ugly solution to this question, but it involves the use of a custom VBA function.

#### Concatenate and Test String

Your SQL statement should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tblName 
WHERE IsSeqHigh([201203] & ";" & [201202] & ";" & ..., 1000);
```

And then, in a VBA module we define:

```
Public Function IsSeqHigh(seq As String, thres As Double) As Boolean
    IsSeqHigh = False

    Dim valStrs() As String
    valStrs = Split(seq, ";")

    For n = 1 To UBound(valStrs) - 1
        If (valStrs(n) >= thres) And (valStrs(n + 1) >= thres) Then
            IsSeqHigh = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next n
End Function
```

#### Another approach

Alternatively, if your schema is fixed and unlikely to change - and you have a primary key value, you can write a VBA function which takes the primary key value and scans the columns for the specific condition you are looking for.

In short, there is no good SQL-only solution that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

You said "orders over 1000", which should exclude Pjt_Id = 1 from the output.  If you actually want orders at least 1000, change `>` to `>=` in this query.

```
SELECT
    p.Pjt_Id,
    p.OrderPriceQ1,
    p.OrderPriceQ2,
    p.OrderPriceQ3,
    p.Customer
FROM TblPureferret AS p
WHERE
       (p.OrderPriceQ1 > 1000 AND p.OrderPriceQ2 > 1000)
    OR (p.OrderPriceQ2 > 1000 AND p.OrderPriceQ3 > 1000);
```

Comment: This is correct for the sample data given by Pureferret. I suspect the asker is looking for a generic technique for an arbitrarily large number of columns, and as far as I can see there is none. For this case, it would require the data be normalized such that the PriceQ column headings are field values. Performing the 'reverse crosstab' necessary for a generic solution would be just as messy as having the explicitly defined where conditions.

Comment: Arbitrarily large number of columns is a much greater challenge, and I preferred to avoid it.  :-)

Comment: Yeah I have 12 columns that I need to account for, so this isn't overly convienient...

Comment: Understood.  Twelve columns would require 11 conditions in the WHERE clause.  Still I'm curious whether you will turn up something more convenient which works with that table design.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
    Pjt_Id  ,OrderPriceQ1 ,OrderPriceQ2 ,OrderPriceQ3 ,Customer  
from 
    table
where 
(
    (OrderPriceQ1>=1000 and OrderPriceQ2 >=1000) or
    (OrderPriceQ1>=1000 and OrderPriceQ3 >=1000) or
    (OrderPriceQ2>=1000 and OrderPriceQ3 >=1000) 
)
```